# How to ensure that an element in the IntArray has not been assigned a value in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

```java
class Solution {
    private Integer[][] memory = //whaterver, It doesn't matter.

    public int leetcode(int[] array) {
        return Math.max(dfs(0, 0), dfs(0, 1));
    }

    int dfs(int status1, int status2) {
        if (status1 == Integer.MAX_VALUE || status2 == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (memory[status1][status2] != null) {
            return memory[status1][status2];
        } else {
            memory[status1][status2] = calculate() + Math.max(dfs(status1 + 1, status2), dfs(status1 + 1, status2 + 1));
            return memory[status1][status2];
        }
    }

    Integer calculate() {
        //...
    }
}
```

As shown in the above java code, in java, you can use `null` to judge whether an element in the array has memorized a certain value. If memorized, you can use it directly. If not, you need to do some calculations and then store the calculated value.

In Kotlin, since IntArray does not accept `null`, is there any good way to achieve similar operations?

thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't try it right now, but I'd expect `Array<Array<Int?>>` to work exactly the same way. `IntArray` is equivalent to `int[]` in Java and `Array<Int?>` should be the equivalent of `Integer[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a variable accept nulls by using `?` 
In Kotlin, the type system distinguishes between references that can hold null (nullable references) and those that cannot (non-null references). For example, a regular variable of type String cannot hold null:

```
var a: String = "abc" // Regular initialization means non-null by default
a = null // compilation error
```

To allow nulls, you can declare a variable as nullable string, written String?:

```
var b: String? = "abc" // can be set null
b = null // ok
print(b)
```

You want an `Int` array that accepts null so write:-

```
fun main() {
    val emptyArray : Array<Int?> = arrayOfNulls(0)
 
    println(emptyArray.size)    // 0
}
```

Check this documentation on [**null safety**](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html) for all the details.Comment for any follow up query